# How sort array by int part of variables value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
Array = ["a5", "O01", "Ap8", "Ma10"];
```

I need sort it by integer part of values in `javascript`, like :

```
O01,a5,Ap8,Ma10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
arr = arr.sort(function(a,b){ return a.match(/\d+/)-b.match(/\d+/) })
```

```js
var arr = ["a5", "O01", "Ap8", "Ma10"];
arr = arr.sort(function(a,b){ return a.match(/\d+/)-b.match(/\d+/) });

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

```html
<code id=result></code>
```